# Height not adjusted when set to float value?

Tags: html, css

I wrote a HTML page where 
**CSS** is

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 992px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
   }
.container{
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding:5px;
    width: 992px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #FFF;
    }
.column{
       margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;
       float:left;
       height: 50px;
       width: 486px;
       background: #0094ff;
       }
```

and **body** is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

when I run this page by removing `float:left` from div class `.column`, the height of `.container` automatically increase but when I set float value in div class `.column` the height of div class `.container` don't increase.
Please can anyone tel me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post a fiddle containing your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `.containar`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `float` element to your `.cointanar` class you will achieve the result you wanted.

Just update your CSS by adding the fololowing properties:

```
.containar { /* shouldn't it be "container"? */
    float: left;
}
```

**Demo fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/yd43nymw/1/